# What is the Fourier transform of $h[n]=\frac{2sin(0.5\pi)}{\pi}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

Note: $j=i=\sqrt{-1}$

What is the Fourier transform of $h[n]=\frac{2\sin(0.5\pi)}{\pi}$?

$$h=\frac{2}{\pi n}\times \frac{e^{j0.5\pi n}-e^{-j0.5\pi n}}{2j}$$

I know by memorization of the conversion formula that the Fourier transform of $e^{j\omega_o n}$ is $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty 2\pi\delta(w-w_o+2\pi k)$ but I don't don't what to do with "n" in the denominator.

Comment: Are you missing a variable in there?

Comment: $h[n] = \mathrm{sinc}\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right)$ so the Fourier Transform is well known to be a rectangle function, scaled appropriately.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question for the steps to take: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2779310/441161

Comment: Do you mean $h[n]=\frac{2sin(0.5\pi n)}{n\pi}$ ?